# How to configure the location button in android google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I want to configure the current location button in android google maps v2 but i have no idea how to. It would be helpful as well if you could tell me how to configure a custom overlay button over the map fragment. I just want this button to point to my custom location which i will provide using geo coord instead of pointing to current location

Answer (score 0):

Here is a facsimile of a button overlay on map that almost matches the google map buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGPS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/mapbutton"
        android:paddingLeft="14dp"
        android:paddingRight="14dp"
        android:text="@string/btnGPS"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

drawable mapbutton.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="2dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#CC444444" />

    <solid android:color="#88FFFFFF" />

</shape>
```

Then like any other button you wire up an onClick() event.
Then in the onClick() for your button you move the map.
   //lat,lon are where your moving the map to.

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newLatLng(lat,lon));
```